# Stored procedure which writes xml into a DB, T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure which writes xml into a DB, T-SQL.

Here is my sample xml (which will have a significant number of `<RECORD>`s in prod environment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<DATA FORMAT_VERSION="1.0">
    <RECORD>
        <NAME>МІЖНАРОДНА ГРОМАДСЬКА ОРГАНІЗАЦІЯ МІЖНАРОДНА АКАДЕМІЯ БІОЕНЕРГОТЕХНОЛОГІЙ</NAME>
        <SHORT_NAME>МАБЕТ</SHORT_NAME>
        <EDRPOU>00011601</EDRPOU>
        <ADDRESS>01001, м.Київ, Шевченківський район, ВУЛИЦЯ ПРОРІЗНА, будинок 8, офіс 426</ADDRESS>
        <STAN>зареєстровано</STAN>
    </RECORD>
</DATA>
```

I pass the path to the xml file in the `@pathToXml` parameter.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LegalContractorsDataSynchronize] 
(
    @pathToXml varchar
)
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DELETE FROM [dbo].[LegalContractors];

INSERT INTO [dbo].[LegalContractors]([Code], [ShortName], [Name], [LegalAddress], [Status])
SELECT CONVERT([Code], [ShortName], [Name], [LegalAddress], [Status])
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK, @pathToXml, SINGLE_CLOB) as x

COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
```

I am using Entity Framework to call the stored procedure. The call just happens (with no errors), but the DB is not updated. I am very sure that I mistyped something in the `INSERT` statement. I followed [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/) example.

Could someone point out how could I fill the three columns in my DB using the data from the respective elements in xml? The columns are `Code`, `ShortName`, `Name`, `LegalAddress` and `Status`.

[image]

**UPDATE**

After the answer being posted I tried the suggested solution. I am getting the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure LegalContractorsDataSynchronize, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near '@pathToXml'.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LegalContractorsDataSynchronize] 
(
    @pathToXml varchar
)
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DELETE FROM [dbo].[LegalContractors];

;WITH XmlFile (xmlData) AS
(
   SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK @pathToXml, SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LegalContractors] ([Code], [ShortName], [Name], [LegalAddress], [Status])
SELECT c.value('(EDRPOU/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS [Code]
   , c.value('(SHORT_NAME/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(512)') AS [ShortName]
    , c.value('(NAME/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(2048)') AS [Name]
   , c.value('(ADDRESS/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(2048)') AS [LegalAddress]
   , c.value('(STAN/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS [Status]
FROM XmlFile CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('/DATA/RECORD') AS t(c);

COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
```

[image]

Comment: `I am using Entity Framework to call the stored procedure.` why are you using this stored procedure at all then? Just create a proper DbContext and entities and use EF to insert the data. Right now you only add overhead to the calls while trying to immitate EF on the server. If you really need this stored procedure, a simple ADO.NET SqlCommand would be better. You could also pass the data as an XML-typed parameter

Comment: Declaring a `VARCHAR` with no length is a [bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). Doubly so if you're intending to stuff a path in there.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the xml size is greater than 1Gb. That is just not feasible (with the infrastructure capacity I have at hand), if we take into account that an app and the db are situated on different servers. The xml is stored on the db server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following. To the best of my knowledge, OPENROWSET() doesn't accept file name parameter as a variable.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
   ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   Code NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   ShortName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   [Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   LegalAddress NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   [Status] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- Method #1
-- XML file is hardcoded
;WITH XmlFile (xmlData) AS
(
    SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\...\Ukraine.xml', /*CODEPAGE = '65001',*/ SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)
INSERT INTO @tbl (Code, ShortName, [Name], LegalAddress, [Status])
SELECT c.value('(EDRPOU/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS [Code]
   , c.value('(SHORT_NAME/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS [ShortName]
    , c.value('(NAME/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS [Name]
   , c.value('(ADDRESS/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS [LegalAddress]
   , c.value('(STAN/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS [Status]
FROM XmlFile CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('/DATA/RECORD') AS t(c);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

-- Method #2
-- dynamic XML file name as a parameter
DECLARE @xml XML
   , @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
   , @fileName VARCHAR(256) = 'c:\...\Ukraine.xml';

SET @sql = N'SELECT @xmlOut = XmlDoc FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ' + QUOTENAME(@fileName,NCHAR(39)) + ', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Tab(XmlDoc)';

EXEC master.sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@xmlOut XML OUTPUT', @xmlOut = @xml OUTPUT;

INSERT INTO @tbl (Code, ShortName, [Name], LegalAddress, [Status])
SELECT c.value('(EDRPOU/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS [Code]
   , c.value('(SHORT_NAME/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS [ShortName]
    , c.value('(NAME/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS [Name]
   , c.value('(ADDRESS/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS [LegalAddress]
   , c.value('(STAN/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS [Status]
FROM @xml.nodes('/DATA/RECORD') AS t(c);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: I updated my question. Could you, please, help me out with the issue I stumbled upon?

Comment: As I stated earlier **"...OPENROWSET() doesn't accept file name parameter as a variable..."**. I updated the answer.

Comment: I believe that you are wrong. The `OPENROWSET` does support the file name. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): `'data_file' Is the full path of the data file whose data is to be copied into the target table.`.

Comment: @hellouworld: it supports a *literal file name*, not a variable. The syntax explicitly says so (`'data_file'`, not `@string_variable | 'data_file'`). The statement would have to be built dynamically.

Comment: Jeroen, please connect with me on the LinkedIn.